# Designer tool for Windows Azure Table Storage

Tags: linq-to-entities, azure

I am using Windows Azure Table Storage. I am wondering, if I could use any designer tool. 
In principle it is Linq to Entities, I think. Maybe I could use a tool for Linq to Entities?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://clumsyleaf.com/products/tablexplorer or as part of AzureXplorer (the same website)

Answer (score 0):

Azure storage uses the Entity Data Model, but it's not exactly the EF. There are no FKs, for example. The closest thing I've seen to a designer is [this commercial product](https://web.archive.org/web/20130305093232/http://www.cerebrata.com:80/Products/CloudStorageStudio/Default.aspx).

**Edited to add** MS just [announced](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/jnak/june-2010-release-of-the-windows-azure-tools-sdk) a read-only table explorer in the June 2010 Azure SDK/Tools.